# Paperclip on docker doesn't upload image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have an issue with paperclip when using it with rails under docker development environment,
I followed all the steps on the [README](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) to add an image to an existing model, everything works no errors but the image is not uploading locally, even I tried to upload to S3 directly and the same issue no errors at all and image is missing folders are empty?

my code is clean I tried it out of docker and it works, any suggestions ?

to mention I even tried carrierwave and it works very well but I do love to use paperclip I do find it more lightweight and powerful.

Comment: Can you tell us more about your setup: Docker image, ruby version, rails version, etc ... Pretty hard to help if you give us no clue

Comment: Thank's for you reply, My Docker image was ruby 2.3.1-slim, rails 5.0.1.
and actually I found a quick solution by changing the docker image to the full ruby 2.3.1 and it did the trick, The problem was the slim image is missing some dependencies that paperclip needs to process.

if you have any idea about what might be the real issue it will be very helpful.

Comment: I am also using ruby slim and to make it work I added `imagemagick` and `file` dependencies. Since imagemagick uses file command internally to determine the mime type.

Comment: @Chris can you please provide me with that part of your docker compose file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my Dockerfile

```
# Use the barebones version of Ruby 2.3.
FROM ruby:2.3.1-slim

# Optionally set a maintainer name to let people know who made this image.
MAINTAINER Chris de Bruin <chris@studytube.nl>

# Install dependencies:
# - build-essential: To ensure certain gems can be compiled
# - nodejs: Compile assets
# - imagemagick: converting images
# - file: needed by paperclip
# - wkhtmltopdf: generating pdf from html
# - libxml2: needed for nokogiri
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -qq -y --no-install-recommends \
      build-essential libmysqlclient-dev git-core imagemagick wkhtmltopdf \
      libxml2 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev nodejs file

# Set an environment variable to store where the app is installed to inside
# of the Docker image. The name matches the project name out of convention only.
ENV INSTALL_PATH /backend
RUN mkdir -p $INSTALL_PATH

# This sets the context of where commands will be ran in and is documented
# on Docker's website extensively.
WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH

# Ensure gems are cached and only get updated when they change. This will
# drastically increase build times when your gems do not change.
COPY Gemfile Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock

RUN bundle install

# Copy in the application code from your work station at the current directory
# over to the working directory.
COPY . .

# Ensure the static assets are exposed through a volume so that nginx can read
# in these values later.
VOLUME ["$INSTALL_PATH/public"]

# The default command that gets ran will be to start the Puma server.
CMD bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

So you should have your own `Dockerfile` and use this in your `docker-compose.yml`